# CI on EC2 is giving 404 on all requests

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, codeigniter, amazon-ec2

I dont know if it's becuse of $routes[] configs I have written or anything cause simply putting a CI in the server bring brings the welcome message fine. This's not even for the .htaccess I cause removing htaccess also results in the 404 for any request.
I have this .htaccess in the app folder and system folder

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond $1 ^(application|system|private|logs)
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/access_denied/$1 [L]
  RewriteCond $1 ^(index\.php|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico|public|assets|resources|css|js|images)
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [L]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

And this .htaccess in the root to redirect for maintenance index and and allowing to the current development folder:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(index.php|x-folder|ci2) [NC]
 RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]
```

And my route.php looks like this:

```
   $route['default_controller'] = 'site/home';
   $route['404_override'] = '';

  /********** *********************Admin routes****************/
  $route['admin']='admin/user/login/' ;
  $route['admin/home']='admin/home' ;
  $route['admin/gallery']='admin/home/gallery' ;
  $route['admin/calendar']='admin/home/calendar' ;
```

And in the config I have changed to important config to:

```
  $config['base_url']= 'http://example.com.bd/';
  $config['index_page'] = '';
```

FYI: My app in the localhost works just fine. 
I'm on EC2(Amazon) on which the current php version is 5.2.3--which codeigniter gracefully supports and mysql>5.5

I'm really stuck Can anyone get me outta this hell please !?

Comment: how come you have a default_controller set to some clean url (site/home/)? It should rather point to site/home where home is home.php

Comment: Indeed,Yes it is. Edited!

Comment: Could u see anything here? How could I solve this?

Comment: did it work? Are you still getting 404s?

Comment: @MohammedAshiq No..No I mean I had it site/home from the begining I just mistyped on the question..moreover CI avoids a trailing slash. Any way I dont have it in my route. Could u suggest anything?

Comment: Can you put your root folder structure? Do you have the domain mapped to the root folder or you have a folder inside the apache root called your site_name.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47879/discussion-between-mohammed-ashiq-and-edam)

Comment: Yes It's on site_name named x-folder

Answer (score 3):

As Sean mentioned by default EC2 sets AllowOverride to None which prohibits your .htaccess to function. Mine is an AMI machine and following are the steps I followed to get it to work from the terminal.

1. sudo nano /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
2. Look for `<Directory "/var/www/html">`
3. Edit "AllowOverride none" to "AllowOverride all"
4. Press "ctrl+o", "enter" and then "ctrl+x" to exit.
5. sudo service httpd restart

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the answer for this should be removing the trailing "/" in config like

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'site/home';
```

and make rename the default controller to be home.php

I guess the htaccess seems to be right. And should work.

remove all the trailing slash in routes's url values. for example $route['admin'] has the trailing slash after login like "login/". Use them only if you have a get variable passed. Eg.,

```
$route['view-page/(:num)'] = "admin/admin/view_page/$1";
```

where you can get this variable as

```
public function view_page(page_number){
    // your super code goes here!
}
```

This is the problem you were facing I think.

## -----------------------UPDATE----------------

## make sure you enable mod_rewrite.c first

```
# .htaccess main domain to subdirectory redirect 
# Do not change this line. 
RewriteEngine on 
# Change yourdomain.com to be your main domain. 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?yourdomain.com$ 
# Change 'x-folder' to be the directory your codeigniter is residing. 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/x-folder/ 
# Don't change the following two lines. 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
# Change 'x-folder' to be the directory your codeigniter is residing. 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /x-folder/$1  
# Change yourdomain.com to be your domain again. 
# Change 'x-folder' to be the directory you will use for your main domain 
# followed by / then the main file for your site, Ive used index.php. 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?yourdomain.com$  
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ x-folder/index.php [L]
```

put this in .htaccess residing at /var/www/html .. lets give a try

Comment: I have changed some that had trailing slash But it still 404!

Answer (score 0):

By default an AMI instance on EC2 is going to have `AllowOverride None` set within `<Directory "/var/www/html"></Directory>` in your httpd.conf. If you change that to `AllowOverride All` it will allow Apache to use the .htaccess file in your CodeIgniter directory.